# Proxmox | /etc/default/pveproxy

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxmox

i have a small problem.
I was trying to disable access to the proxmox web panel via the ip address and enable it via my domain.
As i saw on the proxmox website (https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/pveproxy.8.html) i can create the pveproxy file for Host based Access Control. I did setup a nginx reverse proxy that points to 127.0.0.1:8006 and i did create the pveproxy file with the following content:

```
ALLOW_FROM="127.0.0.1"
DENY_FROM="all"
POLICY="allow"
```

But somehow i still can access my proxmox web ui via the ip address of the server... Does anyone know why?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather use

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 8006 -j DROP
apt-get install iptables-persistent -y
```

confirm to save current rules ipv4 and ipv6 and you are done, in case you need to access it again just delete this iptable rule
Better is to limit access to port 8006 only to my own IP address only, or use fail2ban and setup rule to block IP forever after tries 2-3 unsuccess. login. to proxmox GUI.